# click on a hidden web element while it's hidden

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write tests. Sometimes it happens that a web element on which I want to click is not visible yet as it may be hidden under other elements. I know that we can use `action.moveToElement` or `driver.executeScript` but I was wondering if there is any way that I can force Selenium to click on that element that is covered by another while it's hidden (not on the one that is covering it) ?

Comment: Selenium simulates an user navigation. An user cannot click in the element in this condictions without scroll the page to button became visible. I recommend you write an method to move the element to center of the screen before click

Comment: @StriterAlfa thanks for your reply, but as I said I know the way how to get the element visible, so i was wondering if there is any methods in Selenium or any other frameworks ttat can click an element while it's hidden